# How can i remove packages without other packages?

Tags: 13.04

I'm using 13.04, and I want to remove unused packages. Ex. gnome-power-manager, but i can't.

```
bekir@home:~$ sudo apt-get remove gnome-power-manager 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  gnome-power-manager ubuntu-desktop
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 1.690 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
```

I don't want to remove ubuntu-desktop because he contains other packages. I want to make minimal/simply ubuntu system for me.

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Any reason for why you want to remove such a basic package? What are you trying to accomplish? A minimal Ubuntu installation? Almost all desktop systems have ACPI support and removing the power manager isn't really what I'd recommend.

Comment: Yes, you right. I want to simply and minimal ubuntu system.

Comment: Okay, please include that in your question, by editing it. I'm updating my answer to this. Suggestion: next time asking a question, please include this from the beginning - you'll receive better answers if you include what you're trying to do in the first place. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ubuntu-desktop` is a *metapackage*. It is empty, and only contains metadata such as dependencies and a description, to provide a simple way to install a whole desktop environment. It will also make it possible for to "push" *new* packages to be installed. This can be very much helpful over the five years Ubuntu is supported when the development of an application has stopped and they want to provide an alternative by default.

As `gnome-power-manager` is a hard dependency of the `ubuntu-desktop` package, you can't simply remove it without breaking the `ubuntu-desktop` package installation. And this is what APT is telling you here: it can only proceed with your decision to break the metapackage requirements. You can proceed with removing both packages, but that will make upgrades a bit harder, as you will have to handle any new packages yourself.

```
$ apt-cache show ubuntu-desktop
Package: ubuntu-desktop
Priority: optional
Section: metapackages
Installed-Size: 57
[...]
Source: ubuntu-meta
Version: 1.267.1
Depends: alsa-base, alsa-utils, [...], gnome-power-manager, [...]
[...]
Description-en: The Ubuntu desktop system
 This package depends on all of the packages in the Ubuntu desktop system
 .
 It is also used to help ensure proper upgrades, so it is recommended that
 it not be removed.
[...]
```

In case you want a very minimal Ubuntu system with only the packages you really pick yourself, then:

- Whenever installing new package, be sure to omit the recommended (but not required) packages, by using an `apt-get` option:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends packagename
  ```

  or when using `aptitude`:

  ```
  sudo aptitude install --without-recommends packagename
  ```

  This significantly minimizes the amount of packages installed as the result of the single package selected. However, not all packages have separated hard dependencies and recommended ones separated in the requirements.
- *don't* install `ubuntu-desktop`, but `ubuntu-minimal`. You'll have to install Ubuntu using the Server CD and specify you want a minimal install by pressing <kbd>F4</kbd> on the first screen (see below).

  [image]

  Then after installation, you'll have a non-GUI installation. Install the `ubuntu-desktop` desktop without the recommended packages (see above for how) for a minimal Unity installation, or consider a more minimal GUI installation with LXDE: `lubuntu-core`. Don't worry about having installed using the Server CD. The Ubuntu flavour is just a set of packages.

Comment: OMG!, Thanks but I don't want unused packages in my system :/ It is so frustrating :(